# array.remove(0) removing more than one element

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

I'm working on a scrolling game with LibGdx.

In the render method, I get some data from an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Enemy>> enemies;`

I dinamically add ArrayList to `enemies`, then I pass it to a method which iterate and draw on screen. The method also handle the removing of the entire row when this is no more visible on the screen.

So, in short, I add and remove dinamically items from this array.
Unfortunately, it seems like the removing step is removing more than it should.

I will try to put a valid code next so that you can undestand better.

```
public class Enemy extends ... implements .. {
    [getters and setters]
}

public class GameRenderer {
    ...
    // Enemies
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Enemy>> enemies;
    ...

    private void drawEnemies(float delta) {

        // Get Enemy Array
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {

            for (Enemy enemy : enemies.get(i)) {
                drawEnemy(enemy, delta);
            }
        }

    }

    public void addEnemiesToArray(ArrayList<Enemy> enemiesRow) {
        enemies.add(enemiesRow);
    }
}

private boolean drawEnemy(Enemy enemy, float delta) {
    // get info from enemy and draw
    if (enemy.getY() <= 0)
        enemies.remove(0);
}
```

Then, everything is called from a Processor class:

```
    public void update(float delta) {

    [methods...]

    switch (mRace.getRaceState()) {

        case RUNNING:
            mRace.update(delta, 1);
            if (enemyReference.canSpawnNewLine() && enemyReference.getY() < 350) {
                enemyReference.setCanSpawnNewLine(false);
                spawnNewLine();
            }
            break;

    }

    mRenderer.render(mRace.getRaceState(), mRace.getOldRaceState(), delta);
}

public void spawnNewLine() {
    ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = getEnemiesArray(numOfEnemies(), 0);
    enemyReference = enemies.get(0);
    mRenderer.addEnemiesToArray(enemies);
}
```

My problem is that the enemies.remove(0) method in `drawEnemy` removes more than the first row, it removes 2 or 3 rows at a time. How can I handle this?

Comment: Can you add some source code showing what type each list element (row) is, how you create it & add it to the list, and then explain how you know that a certain other list element apart from 0 has also been removed.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your program with a debugger? `remove(0)` will only ever remove the first element of the list and not any others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please have a look, I've rewritten my question. Sorry about it, it was a long day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @hoaz for the precious suggestions!

I've figured a way out to my problem, I handle the removing of the row outside the rendering method.

In my Processor class:

```
// variable:
private ArrayList<Enemy> enemiesRef;
```

In the update method:

```
switch (mRace.getRaceState()) {

        case RUNNING:
            mRace.update(delta, 1);
            if (enemyReference.canSpawnNewLine() && enemyReference.getY() < 350) {
                enemyReference.setCanSpawnNewLine(false);
                spawnNewLine();
            }
            // This handle the removing
            if (enemiesRef.get(0).getEnd() <= 0) {
                mRenderer.removeFirst();
                enemiesRef.remove(0);
            }
            break;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is quite possible that you add and remove rows at the same time, concurrency problem? It is hard to say without seeing implementation.

Also consider using `LinkedList` as it is better optimized for remove operations which occur in the middle of the list.

`Collections#synchronizedList` might help with concurrency problems.